# Is there any jquery modal plugin which can load web pages

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want to load http://yahoo.com in a modal window on my website. Can some one suggest me any jquery based modal plugin for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has a comprehensive list : http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

Just filter out the ones that use jQuery and support iFrames. Fancybox and jquery UI comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have an image and its title contains link you want to open in dialog.

```
<img title="link.html" class="linkimage">


 $(".linkimage").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var horizontalPadding = 10;
        var verticalPadding = 10;

        $('<iframe   class="externalSite" src="' + this.title + '" />').dialog({
            title: 'HTS',
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 800,
            height: 700,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            autoResize: true,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: "black"
            }
        }).width(800 - horizontalPadding).height(500 - verticalPadding);
    });
```